# How can I turn my DataFrame into a Radar Chart using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame I want to turn into a Radar Chart. The DataFrame looks like this when it's ran...

```
╔═══════════════════╗
║ Col A      Col B  ║
╠═══════════════════╣
║ Home       6.797  ║
║ Other      3.243  ║
║ Used       12.567 ║
║ New        8.985  ║
║ Service    1.345  ║
╚═══════════════════╝
```

I repurposed some code I found on another Stack Overflow question pertaining to Pandas and Radar Charts and it works for the most part except I can't get the values of Col B to align properly within the chart. Below is the code I'm using...

```
df['Z'] = np.ones(len(df))
points = mergedFrame.pivot_table(values='Z', index=['Col A'], columns=['Col B'])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="polar")

theta = np.arange(len(points))/float(len(points))*2.*np.pi
l1, = ax.plot(theta, color="C2", marker="o", label="Name of Col B")

def _closeline(line):
    x, y = line.get_data()
    x = np.concatenate((x, [x[0]]))
    y = np.concatenate((y, [y[0]]))
    line.set_data(x, y)
[_closeline(l) for l in [l1]]

ax.set_xticks(radar)
ax.set_xticklabels(points.index)
plt.legend()
plt.title("Title")
plt.show()
```

And the chart looks like this...

[image]

Since I'm still such a newbie at Python I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried many things to modify the code including eliminating the first two lines of code and simply putting... `points = df['Col B']` instead but all it did was erase the names around the circle while leaving everything else the same. What am I doing wrong here?

Also how can I fill the area inside the theta with a light green? I tried `l1, = ax.fill(theta, facecolor = 'g', alpha=0.25)` below the `l1, = ax.plot(theta, color="C2", marker="o", label="Name of Col B")` line, but it gave me this error `AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'get_data'` and I can't seem to work it out.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an adaption of the code at [this example](https://python-graph-gallery.com/390-basic-radar-chart/) to get you started with the way your data is stored.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col A': ['home', 'other', 'used', 'new', 'service'],
                   'Col B': [6.797, 3.243, 12.567, 8.985, 1.345]})
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="polar")

# theta has 5 different angles, and the first one repeated
theta = np.arange(len(df) + 1) / float(len(df)) * 2 * np.pi
# values has the 5 values from 'Col B', with the first element repeated
values = df['Col B'].values
values = np.append(values, values[0])

# draw the polygon and the mark the points for each angle/value combination
l1, = ax.plot(theta, values, color="C2", marker="o", label="Name of Col B")
plt.xticks(theta[:-1], df['Col A'], color='grey', size=12)
ax.tick_params(pad=10) # to increase the distance of the labels to the plot
# fill the area of the polygon with green and some transparency
ax.fill(theta, values, 'green', alpha=0.1)

# plt.legend() # shows the legend, using the label of the line plot (useful when there is more than 1 polygon)
plt.title("Title")
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting radar plot]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and learned a lot thank you! Do you know of any way to space the xtick labels out a bit more especially for home so it doesn't over lap with the graph? I couldn't find anything in the documentation [link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) that looked like it might solve that issue but I could totally be missing it.

Comment: I added `ax.tick_params(pad=10)` just with that goal, but didn't update the image

Answer (score 2):

I know the problem has been solved previously, however, I would like to share also another approach which looks easier and can be helpful for anyone who is looking for a more simple way.

Another easy and efficient way to do it is using plotly which very simple, easy and fast compared to matplotlib. For the same problem plotly works 9 to 10 times faster than matplotlib.

Step1: Install plotly:

```
pip install plotly
```

Step2:

```
import plotly.express as px
import time
t1 = time.time()
df00 = pd.DataFrame({'Col A': ['home', 'other', 'used', 'new', 'service'],
                   'Col B': [6.797, 3.243, 12.567, 8.985, 1.345]})
fig = px.line_polar(df00, r='Col B', theta='Col A', line_close=True)
fig.show()
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

[image]
For more details, refer to the following link https://plotly.com/python/radar-chart/